# Navigation dots in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have data from locations along a gradient and would like to add some navigation dots above a shiny plot to indicate to the user where there are along the gradient.  I'm not sure how to go about making the dots though.

Probably better explained in pictures, so here is a hodgepodge of what I am after - I copied and pasted the dots onto the image of this example app.  The fourth dot is shaded when the fourth location is selected, etc.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

## sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- rbindlist(lapply(1:6, function(i) 
  list(x=(x=runif(100,-4,4)), y=rnorm(100,x^2,i), loc=rep(i,100))))

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("dots"),
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("loc", "Location", 1:6)),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(y ~ x, data=dat[loc == input$loc]))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to make this happen?  Full working solution not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could send custom messages to the client side (for an example see http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html) and set up your dots in a combination of js and html.
Alternatively you could set up a second plot (`plot(1:6,rep(0,6),col=c(1,1,1,2,1,1))` perhaps... might look better with a gpplot version) and try and style it to look appropriate, then include it as a second `renderPlot` that is positioned above your main plot.